# Правильное написание географических названий

Tags: дефис

Здравствуйте.
Скажите, пожалуйста, географические названия типа Юго-Восточная Азия пишутся через дефис. Как я поняла, согласно правилу, при котором названия, составленные из основы восточно-, северо-, западно-, южно-, пишутся через дефис. А почему тогда Североамериканский материк? Или Северо-Американский материк? В разных статьях по-разному. Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Юго-Восточная Азия - это имя собственное, в которое входит сложное прилагательное с дефисным написанием "юго-восточный".

Прилагательное "североамериканский" пишется слитно, так как оно образовано на основе сочетания с подчинительной связью "Северная Америка", например: североамериканские реки - реки, протекающие в Северной Америке.

В составе имени собственного "североамериканский" пишется с прописной буквы: "В основании Североамериканского материка (материка Северная Америка) находится древняя платформа".

Answer (score 0):

> > Как я поняла, согласно правилу, при котором названия, составленные из основы восточно-, северо-, западно-, южно- пишутся через дефис.

Нет.
Юго-западный ветер, южнорусский говор, североамериканский материк.

Сравните: южный и западный, южная Россия, Северная Америка.

Answer (score 0):

Поднимаю вопрос Skipper, так как в сети упоминается, что в словаре под ред. Лопатина "Прописная или строчная?" указано "Северо-Американский континент" и "Южно-Американский континент". Если у кого-нибудь есть последнее издание, проверьте, пожалуйста. Хотелось бы знать точно.